# Replace content jquery

Tags: jquery, each

Wanna replace images

HTML:

```
    <a href="#"><img src="products.jpg"  alt="products" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="another-image.jpg"  alt="another-image" /></a>
```

Comment: why not assign a class to your <img> tags then define a single click function against all tags with that class?

Comment: But if i click one image with one class, wouldn't all other images with class also be affected?

Comment: Not if the click handler refers to `this` instead of repeating the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you change images sources save them using jQuery function **.data()**. Then, when you click them restore src property. Something like this:

```
if ( $(window).width() <= 480 ) {

    $('img').each(function (i, k) {
        $(k).data('src', $(k).attr('src'));
        $(k).attr('src', 'temp_image.jpg');
    });

    $('img').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
    });
}
```

**Ref:** http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @user1959901 You're welcome. Don't forget to always upvote the answer you find best suitable.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy.

First of all, .click() binds functions to event click with the object called on. You can't (well you can, but it will not work as you expect) bind events inside of a .each()

Try something like this:

```
<div id="banner">
    <a href="#"><img src="banner.jpg" id="realImg1" alt="banner" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="another-image.jpg" id="realImg2" alt="another-image" /></a>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var counter = 0;
        var toggle_images = function () {

              if (counter % 2) // if pair, change all pics to "dummy.jpg"
              {
                  $('img').each(function
                  ({
                        $(this).attr('src', 'dummy.jpg');
                  };
              }
              else  // if odd restore its initial src (you can recycle the value in alt)
              {
                   $('img').each
                   ({
                       // get the name from the alt property and append '.jpg'
                       var pic_path = $(this).attr('alt') + '.jpg'
                       $(this).attr('src', pic_path); 
                   });
              }
              counter += 1;

        };

        $('img').click(toggle_images);  // bind the event
</script>
```